# Dart meaning of Switch statements intended for interpreters or scanners

Tags: dart, switch-statement

In the [dart documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#switch-and-case) there is a little note that say

> Note: Switch statements in Dart are intended for limited circumstances, such as in interpreters or scanners.

I want to know what interpreters and scanners are and what they mean with that.

Answer (score 0):

Interpreters and Scanners are code that typically looks at one character/byte at a time. Switch is probably optimized for that.